# Не устанавливается linux

Tags: linux, install, asus

Проблема такая, пытаюсь установить linux, загружаюсь с флешки и при появлении логотипа система зависает. Пробовал разные дистрибутивы, разные флешки, разные программы записи, на разных компах записывать - результата нет. Ноут asus rog процессор i5

Comment: Дистрибутив, какой пытаетесь установить, укажите.

Comment: Как вы определяете, что зависает? Сколько времени ждать пробовали?

Comment: @alvoro Пробовал ununtu, mint, kali, elementary os

Comment: @andreymal около часа ждал.

Comment: Когда появляется логотип, жмите Esc — логотип должен пропасть и должна появиться чёрненькая консоль, и возможно там написано что-нибудь интересное

Comment: Что то интересное?

Comment: Все приведенные вами дистрибутивы основаны на Debian. Посмею предположить, что проблема может быть в Debian. Попробуйте arch. Он, если я не ошибаюсь, с debian не связан

Comment: Вам надо попасть в bios (или что там на этои ноуте) и "тыкнуть пальцем" компьютеру, что надо грузится с флешки. Здесь предлагают несколько способов https://archlinux.org.ru/forum/topic/18618/?page=1#post-206648

Comment: Так у меня же с флешки загружается, при чем тут bios?

Comment: "при появлении логотипа система зависает" - логип Asus или ОС?

Comment: При появлении логотипа ОС

Comment: Через dd флешку записывать пробовали? Если debian-based дистрибутив не принципиален, то попробуйте поставить manjaro или antergos. Там тоже графический интерфейс загрузки. Просто 4 дистра и один баг выглядит странно.

Comment: Может отключение uefi поможет?

Comment: Нажал клавишу esc при появлении логотипа.  Загрузка зависает после появления пункта Starting CUPS printing spooler /server   [ok]

Comment: Попробуйте ctrl+alt+f[1-8] Возможно, перекинет в виртуальный терминал

Comment: @Данил я бы посоветовал конкретно указать в вопросе тип дистрибутива, программы создания загрузочной флешки. так советы будут конкретнее.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего не правильно записываешь флэшку. Если ноутбук новый то скорее всего стоит UEFI, попробуй записать программой UNetbootin. Также не забывай проверять сигнатуру скачанных образов.

Comment: Флешка записывалась правильно. На текущий момент поставил минт последней версии. Все установилось без проблем и работает отлично, хотя убунту(тоже последней версии) не хочет нормально работать(до этого удалось поставить убунту, она проработала 3 недели и перестала графическая оболочка загружаться)